# OpenLayers How to modify a linestring and display in form field as wkt

Tags: select, openlayers, wkt

I have a linestring - vector layer with a draw-action (which works well yay) and a separate select and modify-action (which doesn't).
What I would like to do, is select a line, modify it and then display it in a formfield in wkt format.

I've been playing around with the function that I already use for the draw-action, but I just can't get it to work for the modify.
While using `.on("change"` leads to no feedback at all, with `.on("modifyend"` gives an >Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getGeometry' of undefined.
I just can't find out, where I'm going wrong.. any help would be very much appreciated.

```
function Trail_Modify() {

    var selectTrails= new ol.interaction.Select({
        layers: [lineLayer, lyrTrails]
    });
    map.addInteraction(selectTrails);   

    modifyTrails= new ol.interaction.Modify({
        features: selectTrails.getFeatures()
    });
    map.addInteraction(modifyTrails);   

    modifyTrails.on("modifyend", function(e) {
        var feature= e.feature;
        var format = new ol.format.WKT(),
            wkt = format.writeGeometry(feature.getGeometry());
        $("#trailCoords").val(wkt);
    }, this);   
}
```

Comment: The event includes a collection of features so try `var feature= e.features,getArray()[0];`

Comment: Wow, that was easy. Thank you so much! It works fine now
(has to be .getArray and not a comma though, just in case someone has the same problem)